# Less: Passing option when using programmatically (via API)

Tags: less

When using `lessc`on the [commandline](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage), I can pass the option `--modify-var="my-var=my-val"`.

How can I pass the same option when I use less programmatically via [API](http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage) with `less.render(lessInput, options)`?

I would somehow hope that I can set a property in `options` like `{modifyVar:'my-var=my-val'}`. But this seems not to work and I didn't find any documentation regarding this use case.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the options are not described at the API documentation. The easiest way to understanding them, will be by studying the the source of https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc.

Both the options and modifyVars option should be an object. For the `modifyVars` option each variable should be a key of the object. Keys may but don't have to start with a `@`.

Example:

```
var less = require('less/lib/less-node');

var options = {};
options['modifyVars'] = {'color1' : 'blue', '@color2': 'darkblue'};


less.render('@color1: red; @color2:yellow; t {color1: @color1; color2: @color2;}', options)
.then(function(output) {
// output.css = string of css
// output.map = undefined
console.log(output.css);
});
```

The above should output as follows:

```
t {
  color1: blue;
  color2: darkblue;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the link you included is no longer valid. I believe this is the equivalent but anyone here can correct me if that's wrong: https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/packages/less/bin/lessc