# How to detect and print changing variables LESS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I want to create a simple script that changes LESS variables and print the CSS output in a div.

this is my HTML

```html
<input type="text" id="choose-color" onchange="ModifyColorsInLess()">
<button onclick="writeCSS()">aggiorna</button>
<div id="lesscode"></div>
```

This is my js

```js
function writeCSS(){
  var lessCode = '';
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.status === 200 && xmlhttp.readyState === 4){
      lessCode = xmlhttp.responseText;
      new(less.Parser)().parse(lessCode, function (e, tree) {
        document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML =   tree.toCSS().replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
      });

    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET","css/styles.less",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function ModifyColorsInLess() {
  less.modifyVars(
    {
      '@colore-body': $("#choose-color").val()
    }
  );
}
```

The script prints CSS code correctly, but if i insert a new color value in the input type="text" and call the writeCSS function, it doesn't print my variable edit.
I think the problem is that "modifyvar" does not change the file "styles.less", so when I call the function writeCSS() does not detect changes made.
is there a way to print the css dynamically detecting changes made with modifyvar?

Comment: In you snippet the `modifyVars` option should be passed to the `parse` function ([see for example](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/v1.7.5/dist/less-1.7.5.js#L7652)). `modifyVars` of the global `less` object applies only to those less files this global `less` automatically evaluates on page load. `new(less.Parser)()` object is actually a *new* parser object that inherits nothing from document's global `less`.

Comment: I'm new in less.js ... how could I rewrite my script using your suggestions?

Comment: Something [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/a34b07f7acd403c129de#file-29437697-js-L9) probably (non optimized). I did not actually test if that works (I just do not have any Less 1.x sandboxes around since I've switched to v2.x a while ago)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**
When you allow the compiled styles are directly applied on your page, you can simply call [`modifyVars](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables) as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Less Example</title>
<script>
less = {
    env: "development"
}    
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="t.less">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.0/less.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function writeCSS(){
        less.modifyVars({
          'colore-body': document.getElementById('choose-color').value
        });  
   }        


</script>   
</head> 
<body>
<input type="text" id="choose-color">
<button onclick="writeCSS()">aggiorna</button>
<div id="lesscode"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/14MIt4gGCrMyXjgwCsoc

**end update**

Based on [How to show the compiled css from a .less file in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798122/how-to-show-the-compiled-css-from-a-less-file-in-the-browser/25325750), [How to update variables in .less file dynamically using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208451/how-to-update-variables-in-less-file-dynamically-using-angularjs/28429153) and [Less: Passing option when using programmatically (via API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960681/less-passing-option-when-using-programmatically-via-api/29357129) (you should also read: http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage) you should be able to use the code like that shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Less Example</title>
<script>
less = {
    env: "development"
}    
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.0/less.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function writeCSS(){
    var lessCode = '';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        var options = {}
        options['modifyVars'] = {'colore-body' : document.getElementById('choose-color').value}     
        lessCode = xmlhttp.responseText;
        less.render(lessCode, options, function (error, output) {
        if(!error) {
        document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML = output.css;
        }
        else document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">' + error + '</span>';
        });

      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","styles.less",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>   
</head> 
<body>
<input type="text" id="choose-color">
<button onclick="writeCSS()">aggiorna</button>
<div id="lesscode"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/YbdtOwOeQPC1k9Vq4ZBv

<strike>And finally based on [Force Cache-Control: no-cache in Chrome via XMLHttpRequest on F5 reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356025/force-cache-control-no-cache-in-chrome-via-xmlhttprequest-on-f5-reload) you can prevent caching of your source file with the following code:</strike>

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","t.less?_=" + new Date().getTime(),true);
```

In the above the `env: "development"` setting prevents your source files from caching. To clear the cache otherwise, you should call `less.refresh(true)` before your less.render call.

> i have another little problem, if in my less file there is a reference
>   to another less file like this(@import "another.less") script doesn't
>   work.

Make sure that `another.less` in the above is in the same folder as your `styles.less` file. Notice that import (when using less in browser) are read with a XMLHttpRequest too. So your imported files should be readable by browser and their paths should be relative to the `styles.less` file. Also see http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-relativeurls

Comment: great! thank you so much!!! i have another little problem, if in my less file there is a reference to another less file like this(@import "another.less") script doesn't work. with the inspector web i see an error message like this (failed to resource file). if i use one single file .less script works very good... is there any explanation?

Comment: the paths are correct... with mozilla i receive this warning : "A request synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of the negative effects on the user experience. For more information see http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/" maybe it is the problem...

Comment: i doe not think that is the reason not reaching your files, also see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2384